# How to tell what packages correspond to what kernel bundled inside of a Packages.gz

Tags: repository, pxe

We are trying to install images via a netboot image from our PXE server. Our PXE points to a local repo that pulls down new updates nightly from another repo which is out of our control.

Occasionally we hit an issue where the packages provided from the nightly update do not match with the netboot image, causing it to fail.

By looking through a Packages.gz file provided from the repo, how can we tell what package corresponds to what kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Packages does not provide information about kernel behind it works. Some packages only may **depend** on some specific kernel version. This dependencies are written in package meta. Some distros provides suffixes with distro version for their packages (like Fedora).

I hope you know about nightly updates and all risks about it. I assume that after nightly updates `Packages.gz` may be inconsistent with retrieved packages, so you need update it manually as following (fragment from official documentation):

> Every time you put new files in the directory, you'll have to scan the
>   directory and update aptitude:

```
$ ( cd /var/lib/mydebs && dpkg-scanpackages . | gzip > Packages.gz )
$ aptitude update
```

More specific info located at [Debian Repository Setup](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup).